# Loading SQL data into iPython

Tags: python, sql, ipython

I'm trying to load a database into iPython so that I can run loops over the data with Python. So far I have the below query that will load the data, which can be printed to iPython:

```
> sql = %sql SELECT * FROM products

> print sql

+----+--------------+---------------+-------+
| id |    Product   |      Make     | Price |
+----+--------------+---------------+-------+
| 0  |    Product1  |      Make1    |   5   |
| 1  |    Product2  |      Make2    |   1   |
| 2  |    Product3  |      Make2    |   8   |
```

However I'm having trouble imputing these results into Python. Is there a good way to store data like this into python variables so that I can run loops over the data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check examples [here](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql):

You can do `sql[ROW][COLUMN]`, `sql[0][1]` will return Product1. If you iterate over sql it will iterate over rows.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely check out the Python package Pandas. You can import data from a SQL query into a Pandas dataframe with the read_sql_query function.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_info) 
sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

Then you can perform functions on columns. You can even plot your data easily. This may be a more powerful tool than you're looking for, but if you want to do more than just loop over your data, it's worth checking out.

10 minutes to Pandas:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html